# Spring Security: LDAP Authentication for given set of Connection URL & Credentials

Tags: spring-security, ldap

I've been given the following LDAP configuration I need to use for authentication. How does this translate into Java code?

> ## ext ldap over SSL
>
> ext.secure.adapter.ConnectionURL=ldap://ext_host:999
>   encrypted.ext.secure.adapter.UserName=CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=ext-pre,DC=corp-pre,DC=com
>   encrypted.ext.secure.adapter.Password=HelloWorld1
>
> ## corp ldap over SSL
>
> corp.secure.adapter.ConnectionURL=ldap://corp_host:888
>   encrypted.corp.secure.adapter.UserName=CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=corp-pre,DC=com
>   encrypted.corp.secure.adapter.Password=HelloWorld1

Does the below code look right?

```
package com.company.boot;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin();
    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends
            GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth
                    .ldapAuthentication()
                    .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
                    .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
                    .contextSource()
                    .url("ldap://ext_host:999/CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=ext-pre,DC=corp-pre,DC=com");
        }
    }
}
```

The above code only accommodates one ConnectionURL. How do I included the other ConnectionURL?

Answer (score 0):

Just add it twice with different URL's. First it will authenticate against `ldap://ext_host:999`and on not finding will check in `ldap://corp_host:888`

```
        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
            .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
            .contextSource()
            .url("ldap://ext_host:999/CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=ext-pre,DC=corp-pre,DC=com");

            auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
            .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
            .contextSource()
            .url("ldap://corp_host:888/CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=corp-pre,DC=com");
}
```